# How to change the width of reCaptcha (v2) with js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I am trying to set a width for reCaptcha (v2) but JavaScript can't locate the div that I need to apply the styling to (`<div class="rc-anchor rc-anchor-normal rc-anchor-light">`).

I've tried Jquery, vanilla JS and the mix of both to achieve this but nothing seems to work. I mainly tried to give that `div` an `ID` (`document.getElementsByClassName("rc-anchor-normal")[0].setAttribute("id", "captchadiv");`) but somehow JS can't find the object unless I use inspect element on the captcha and find the `div` myself.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could achieve this?

### My Full Code

```
var width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var form = width - (width * 0.10);
var input = $("#name").outerWidth();

setTimeout(() => { document.getElementsByClassName("rc-anchor-normal")[0].style.width = input; }, 5000);
```

Comment: I have never used reCaptcha but as it is a third party plugin/library, I assume it has some sort of iFrame and will be loaded into the DOM after the page has loaded so you will need to wait. Try wrapping your code with `setTimeout(() => { /* code here */ }, 5000)`. This will prevent it from executing for 5 seconds. If this works then you know this is the issue...

Comment: Then I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`.

Comment: Post your full code...

Comment: Update your question... Don't post the code as a comment!

Comment: unfortunately, it's not possible to get the desired width without using transform hacks. But captcha has a data-size attribute which can be used to apply prefixed width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I found that worked for me was to scale the content and not the `captcha`.

Answer (score 1):

try this workaround:

```
.g-recaptcha {
transform:scale(0.77);
transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

Update:

you can use the onload parameter in the url:
    *src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var onloadCallback = function() {
    //set CSS
  };
</script>
```

[Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_param)

Comment: I know this works but It's not what I was looking for.

Comment: The above might work.  Also, I think that there is a setting in the API that allows you to specify a basic size when you render, "size": "compact" vs. "normal"

Comment: check my update. Google gives you a callback parameter which loads your function when all dependencies are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display). There's an api that lets you configure the size as either compact or normal. The attribute is called `data-size`. Here's a codeblock of how to use it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
      'size' : 'compact'
    });
  };
</script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
    async defer>
</script>
```

Comment: I already know about that I just want to set the WIDTH, this is not what I was looking for.

Comment: Have you tried putting your typical jQuery code INSIDE the callback? Put it after `grecaptcha` has rendered.

Comment: No matter what JS or Jquery I put in the callback, the captcha still loads just the same as It usually does. No change in size.